# How to know that computer user use browser to visit websites by using http or https in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, networking

I am doing windows application and trying to get information whenever computer user use http / https to request any information from internet. I am trying to get information requested url by computer user from http or https (for any type of browser)

Comment: Use a proxy server or network driver. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This seems widely off topic. @CodeCaster mentioned two alternatives. .Consider asking this on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ (both pages belong to StackExchange)

Comment: @Sascha Well, actually OP is asking for how to do it in a WPF app... It seems like OP should know how to make a network sniffer. Something like Fiddler...